# how access JtextArea in a JtabbedPane in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

I want to make a program same as notepad with tab option.
I created a tab with JTabbedPane and add TextArea in that.
tab created whit user when program run.
how I can access to JTextArea in selected tab by user to save data and other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Write a class, extending from something like `JPanel`. This class will container a `JTextArea` (presumably within a `JScrollPane`)
- Provide appropriate getters and setters and other functionality you might want to use (set/getText, load/save, whatever)

When you need to add another tab, create an instance of this class, configure as you need.  Generate a unique identifier for it (probably the same as the tab's name) and add it to a `Map` of some kind, keyed to the identifier.

When you need to, using the identifier, get the instance of "editor pane".

Some other useful methods you might need

- [`JTabbedPane#getTitleAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getTitleAt(int))
- [`JTabbedPane#getSelectedIndex`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getSelectedIndex())
- [`JTabbedPane#getComponentAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getComponentAt(int))

Answer (score 1):

Try to access it like this:

```
JTextArea TextArea1= (JTextArea)jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent();
```